# R - Filling a matrix with data from specific data blocks from another matrix

Tags: r

I have my data in a matrix, but it still has lot of unnecessary information in it (due to the process of grabbing the data from mhtml files). I want to "filter" those things out and "collapse" the matrix (so that there is no empty cell between the data), so that after I saved it to an spreadsheet I do not need to do extra clean up on it (would be quite handy when you need to do it for 400+ files).

However, the only way I know of doing this is by using `gsub` and delete the stuff I do not want, before I generate the matrix.

However, since I just need specific blocks of the matrix and I know where those blocks are (I can determine it by using `which` to get the specific cell one row before the block(s) I'm needing) I was thinking, if it is possible to copy out specific data blocks when I know where it starts and where it ends (fixed size of the blocks).

Hence, does somebody know a way to copy several specific areas of an Matrix into a single different matrix when you know the cells, where the data block begins, which has a fixed size (as in colums and rows)?

I kinda have a feeling, that I oversee something, cause it sounds rather easy.

Edit says: dumb me, forgot a data example (hope this works):

```
dput(var_table[1:20,1:6])
structure(c("coration:none", "", "Zeit", "kV", "-------------------------------------------------------", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "", "Phase", "Datum/Zeit", 
"Stufe", "tan-delta-Mittelwert", "Standardabweichung", "Anzahl", 
"color:000000\">Details:", NA, "Spannung", "mA", NA, "12:54:09", 
"12:54:19", "12:54:30", "12:54:39", "12:54:49", "12:55:00", "12:55:10", 
"12:55:20", NA, ".......................", "..................", 
".......................", "........", "..........", "der", NA, 
NA, "Strom", "E-3", NA, "5.8", "5.8", "5.8", "5.8", "5.8", "5.8", 
"5.8", "5.8", NA, ":", ":", ":", ":", ":", "Messungen", NA, NA, 
"tan", NA, NA, "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", 
"3.07", "3.07", NA, "L1", "29-09-2015", "1", "0.343", "0.001", 
"........", NA, NA, "delta", NA, NA, "0.34", "0.34", "0.34", 
"0.34", "0.34", "0.34", "0.34", "0.34", NA, NA, "12:55:20", NA, 
"E-3", "E-3", ":", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "8"), .Dim = c(20L, 6L))
```

Just need the data block from [6:13,1:5].

Second data snippet, same file:

```
structure(c("Phase", "Datum/Zeit", "Stufe", "tan-delta-Mittelwert", 
"Standardabweichung", "Anzahl", "Last", "Prfcfobjekt", "Generator", 
"", "", "Zeit", "kV", "-------------------------------------------------------", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "", "Phase", "Datum/Zeit", 
"Stufe", "tan-delta-Mittelwert", "Standardabweichung", "Anzahl", 
"Last", "Prfcfobjekt", "Generator", ".......................", 
"..................", ".......................", "........", 
"..........", "der", "........................", "VSE-Strom", 
"VSE-Strom", NA, NA, "Spannung", "mA", NA, "12:56:40", "12:56:50", 
"12:57:00", "12:57:10", "12:57:21", "12:57:31", "12:57:41", "12:57:51", 
NA, ".......................", "..................", ".......................", 
"........", "..........", "der", "........................", 
"VSE-Strom", "VSE-Strom", ":", ":", ":", ":", ":", "Messungen", 
":", "........", ".........", NA, NA, "Strom", "E-3", NA, "11.7", 
"11.7", "11.7", "11.7", "11.7", "11.7", "11.7", "11.7", NA, ":", 
":", ":", ":", ":", "Messungen", ":", "........", ".........", 
"L1", "29-09-2015", "1", "0.343", "0.001", "........", "847.6", 
":", ":", NA, NA, "tan", NA, NA, "6.18", "6.18", "6.18", "6.18", 
"6.18", "6.18", "6.18", "6.19", NA, "L1", "29-09-2015", "2", 
"0.355", "0.001", "........", "843.2", ":", ":", NA, "12:55:20", 
NA, "E-3", "E-3", ":", "nF", "32", "2", NA, NA, "delta", NA, 
NA, "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.36", "0.36", "0.36", "0.36", "0.36", 
NA, NA, "12:57:52", NA, "E-3", "E-3", ":", "nF", "66", "6", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "8", NA, "b5A", "b5A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "8", NA, 
"b5A", "b5A"), .Dim = c(32L, 6L))
```

Here I would need just the "Phase" (aka [15:4] and [38:4]), anybody has an idea?

Comment: give a little reproducible example with **data** and **expected output**. You can maybe post the result of `dput(YOURDATA[1:10,1:10])`.

Comment: There you go, I simply forgot it.

Comment: `[15:4] and [38:4]` is unclear. Please correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example-data something like this would work.

code:

```
keepRows <- apply(df1,1,function(x){all(grepl("^(\\d|[:.])+$",x)|is.na(x))})
df2 <- df1[keepRows,]

keepCols <- apply(df2,2,function(x){!all(is.na(x))})
df2[,keepCols]
```

result:

```
#     [,1] [,2]       [,3]  [,4]   [,5]  
#[1,] "1"  "12:54:09" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[2,] "2"  "12:54:19" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[3,] "3"  "12:54:30" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[4,] "4"  "12:54:39" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[5,] "5"  "12:54:49" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[6,] "6"  "12:55:00" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[7,] "7"  "12:55:10" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
#[8,] "8"  "12:55:20" "5.8" "3.07" "0.34"
```

Please note:

1. You have to set the types

   - At the moment all cells are character strings (text). With text you cannot do math. Your second column is a special TIME-Format. You need to convert the columns into there meaningful type. Do research.
2. Do you really want to use a matrix here? You can only have ONE type inside EACH matrix

   - Like I mentioned in 1). 2nd col is time-format. The others are `integer` or `numeric`. Those are 2/3 distinct data.types. In a matrix, you can only have 1.
     So as a first step I would convert `as.data.frame()`.
3. In the above code i'm looking for rows that have only `[NA, NUMBERS, : , . ]`. This might not be general enough for your real data.
4. Type every function you see into r console like this. `?all`, `?apply`, `?grepl`, ... and read!

Comment: I just let it run though my whole file, it works perfectly! I also tested it on two others, worked also exactly as I wished!

ad 1) what do you exactly mean with this?
ad 2) Want to use, it is rather I kinda have to use it, cause using data.frames results into a big mess (at least I do not get it to work properly)
ad 3) As mentioned, I let it run over several files, worked perfectly. 

I added a second data snippet, how would you extract the "Phase" here ([15:4])? That is the last thing missing to make it fully automatically.